# sql query, selecting data through 3 tables

Tags: c#, sql

i have a db like below:
(sorry i couldn't upload the diagram)

group table:

```
grp_id smallint 
grp_name char(50)
```

type table:

```
tp_id smallint 
tp_name char(50)
```

item table:

```
it_id int 
grp_id smallint  
tp_id smallint
```

item table is linked to group table by grp_id, and is linked to type table via tp_id.

the user enter the `grp_name` or `grp_id`,
and i should realize which item have this group and add the type names of them, from type table to a `checklistbox`.

Comment: Post ur code what hav u tried..

Comment: Pretty standard query, what have you tried so far?

Comment: What are you using to connect C# to the database? EF, ADO.NET, or another ORM?

Comment: ado.net, with sqlconnection and sqlcommand classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select it_id, tp_name
from item
inner join type on type.tp_id = item.tp_id
inner join [group] on [group].grp_id = item.grp_id
where [group].grp_id = @groupid or [group].grp_name = @groupname
```

Comment: +1 - I would change the ? to `@groupid` and `@groupname` respectively, but only  if the OP was using ADO.NET.

Comment: you mean somthing like this?`    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("...", connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sth", sth).DbType = DbType.Int16;
               `

Comment: @rene You might want to consider brushing up on SQL basics, see e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp Also, grab a good book on ADO.NET. It will pay for itself very soon.

Comment: @Jetti the Parameter Placeholder name format is dependent on the OleDbProvider used when using ADO.NET.

Comment: @ConradFrix ah ok. I've only ever used the MS SQL Server ADO.NET provider. Thanks for the info!